# Cursor can only have three colours (black, white, and grey)

Tags: nvidia, mouse, cursor

Okay, so I'm not sure if this is an Ubuntu restriction or what, but my cursor can only show three colours: black (as in 0,0,0), white (as in 255,255,255), and some sort of middle-grey. I'm assuming it's 127,127,127 but I haven't checked.

Whenever I use custom cursors, it's always an un-anti-aliased monochrome cursor. The [Bridge](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/999983/) cursors always show up as pure black rather than their grey colour and the non-monochrome Bridge cursors (eg spinning ball cursors) are approximated to the closest one of the three values. Whenever my cursor is supposed to change to a custom cursor (eg [Goodgame Empire](https://empire.goodgamestudios.com/)) it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiDbT.jpg). It should look like [this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/385956920709611551/404374750178181120/IMG_20180120_203955.jpg). I've also tried in Civ 6 with the cursor looking similar and definitely not brown like the cursor is on Windows.

I'm thinking it may be with my Nvidia drivers (384.111 with a GTX 1060 6GB), although since that's the latest I don't know what else I could do.

I'm also using the Numix theme and Papirus icons but I've tried with the default theme and icons and still the same, so it's not an issue with those.

Comment: nVidia driver 390 just came out with more support for GTX Pascal family of GPUs. It's available on Additional Drivers panel today when I looked. I haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: Oh, did it? I'll try that, then. Fingers crossed it'll work

Comment: Installed 390 drivers, unfortunately still have the issue :( Thanks for suggesting it, though! The driver update has made the Ubuntu startup screen actually my monitor's resolution (it was a weird 4:3 stretched display before for some reason) so I suppose thanks for that at least haha